# Не могу найти повторный вход в функцию JavaScript

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Есть задача — два столбца, в правом нужно сопоставить ответы на вопросы из левого. Рабочий пример (временно) можно посмотреть на [сайте](http://romeo-models.ru). Сами вопросы и ответы к ним подгружаются ajax'ом из отдельных файлов (условие задания). Почему-то именно после внедрения этой процедуры варианты ответов стали повторяться по принципу i--. Пожалуйста, подскажите, где ошибка?

Код страницы: index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/question.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Null</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*<![CDATA[*/div.c1 {text-align: center}/*]]>*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Использование JavaScript и элемента INPUT для создания контрольных тестов</li>
    </ul>
    <table width="95%" border="0" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="c1">Сопоставьте значения из списка</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="question_1_"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="question_2_"></div>                
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="question_3_"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="question_4_"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="question_5_"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="c1">
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Проверить" onclick="get_answer()" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <ul>
        <li>Работа с временем в JavaScript</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
    <div id="time_1"></div>
    <div id="time_2"></div>
    <div id="time_3"></div>
    <div id="time_4"></div>
    <div id="time_5"></div>
    <ul>
        <li>Создание IMS-пакетов</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Код ajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function inicialization(){
$.get('/questions/question_1.html', function(data) {
$('#question_1_').html(data);
});
$.get('/questions/question_2.html', function(data) {
$('#question_2_').html(data);
});
$.get('/questions/question_3.html', function(data) {
$('#question_3_').html(data);
});
$.get('/questions/question_4.html', function(data) {
$('#question_4_').html(data);
});
$.get('/questions/question_5.html', function(data) {
$('#question_5_').html(data);
});
});
```

Пример страницы question_1.html (файл с вопросом, подгружаемый через ajax):

```
<script src="script/question.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        Повреждение клетки не возникает вследствие изменения ее генетической программы при:
                <input type="text" class="answer" name="textField" value=" " />
                    <select id="select_1" name="select1" onchange="transfer()">
                        <option value="0">Выберите...</option>
                    </select>
```

Код question.js:

```
$(document).ready(function inicialization(){  
    $(".answer").hide(); //Пока не выбран ответ, скрывает textarea
//Варианты ответов на 1 вопрос
$("#select_1").one("focus", function select_1(){
    $(this).append(new Option('экспрессии патологических генов;', '1', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('репрессии нормальных генов;', '2', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('транслокации генов;', '3', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('изменении структуры генов;', '4', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('* экспрессии генов главного комплекса гистосовместимости.', '5', false, false));
});
//Варианты ответов на 2 вопрос
$("#select_2").one("focus", function select_2(){
    $(this).append(new Option('* уменьшается;', '1', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('не изменяется;', '2', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('увеличивается.', '3', false, false));
});
//Варианты ответов на 3 вопрос
$("#select_3").one("focus", function select_3(){
    $(this).append(new Option('снижение барометрического давления;', '1', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('* снижение парциального давления О2 в воздухе;', '2', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('ультрафиолетовое излучение;', '3', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('низкая температура.', '4', false, false));
});
//Варианты ответов на 4 вопрос
$("#select_4").one("focus", function select_4(){
    $(this).append(new Option('цитоплазматическая мембрана;', '1', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('* ДНК;', '2', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('митохондрии;', '3', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('рибосомы;', '4', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('саркоплазматический ретикулум.', '5', false, false));
});
//Варианты ответов на 5 вопрос
$("#select_5").one("focus", function select_5(){
    $(this).append(new Option('* ослабление процесса внутреннего коркового торможения;', '1', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('усиление процесса коркового торможения;', '2', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('усиление процесса возбуждения;', '3', false, false));
    $(this).append(new Option('патологическая инертность процесса возбуждения.', '4', false, false));
    });
});
//Функция сопостовления варианта ответов с конкретным вопросом
function transfer(){
$("select :selected").each(function sets(index, selected){
    if ($(selected).val() > 0) {
    $(".answer:eq(" + index + ")").val($(selected).text());  //Перемещение ответа в textarea
    $("select:eq(" + index + ")").hide("slow");
    $(".answer:eq(" + index + ")").css("width", "370px")
    $(".answer:eq(" + index + ")").show("slow");
    //Подсчет времени, затраченного на ответ
    count = index + 1;
    var sec=sec+1;
    $("#time_" + count).text("Ответ на " + count + " вопрос занял у вас " + sec + " сек.");     
    }
});
}  
//Проверка ответа
function get_answer(){
var get_answer = [];
$("select :selected").each(function(i, selected){
    get_answer[i] = $(selected).val();
});
if (get_answer=="5,1,2,2,1") {
    alert("Ответ верный!");
    }
    else {
    location.reload();
    alert("Ответ неверный!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

question_X.html загружает script/question.js 
X подгрузок html странички - X запусков процедуры заполнения списков ответов. 
Либо делать script/question_X.js для каждой question_X.html, либо выносить загрузку и запуск question.js в основной документ